# How do I control my dropbox account from Ruby?

Tags: ruby, dropbox

I read the documentation of the Dropbox SDK for Ruby, and couldn't find an example about using my own dropbox account. The examples I saw require that I get an ACCESS_TOKEN from a random user that validates the session for me.

I am the user! I just want to start uploading and deleting files; nothing more.

How do I achieve that?

EDIT:

snippet

```
require 'dropbox_sdk'

APP_KEY = '******'
APP_SECRET = '*****'
ACCESS_TYPE = :dropbox

session = DropboxSession.new(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET)


#I don't want to do this, I just want to know the way of authenticate
#myself with some method that don't need authorization

#-------------------------------------------
session.get_request_token

authorize_url = session.get_authorize_url


puts "AUTHORIZING", authorize_url
puts "Please visit that website and hit 'Allow', then hit Enter here."
gets


session.get_access_token

client = DropboxClient.new(session, ACCESS_TYPE)
puts "linked account:", client.account_info().inspect
```

Comment: ... What examples suggest getting an access token from a random user? What if *you* were that "random" user? Did you create an app as per [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apply) yet? What steps have you taken?

Comment: I agree with Dave, you know you are the user.... but how do the dropbox servers know that when using the api and not doing a login?  Put another way, if no token was used ANYONE could access your dropbox account (in theory), but that's why (in practice) you are required to have the token.

Comment: @DaveNewton I created the app. I'm following this tutorial, https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/authentication#ruby. Newton, do you have experience with dropbox? can you provide me a snippet of code?

Comment: @junky Ok, how then do I get a permanent access token? or How do I authenticate myself? I got the App key and App secret

Comment: A snippet of code for what? My snippets of code would look exactly like the ones in the link you provided.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm sorry, I'm not planing taking advantage of anyone. I'm sorry